# FFmpeg - Converting JPG to AVI issue

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, jpeg, avi

I'm having an issue converting jpg files to avi using ffmpeg.

I use this command:

```
./ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i ~/PycharmProjects/images/test/img%04d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

My files are named img0001.jpg and increase with one each image.

When I run the script I get these messages:

[image: Screenshot]

I get an avi file but it is corrupt.

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` output as text, and not as an image. Text is easier to read, can show all of the output, and is searchable. You can omit most of the `[mjpeg @ 0x7...]` lines from the output.

Comment: They seem to be all different sizes.